# Path based URL redirect between two azure web apps without changing the root domain

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, url-routing

I have two azure web apps like app1 and app2. I have given a custom domain for app1 like this [www.example.com](http://www.example.com). I want to give sub domain that redirects to app2 without changing the app1 custom name like
[www.example.com/app2](http://www.example.com/app2). This URL [www.example.com/app2](http://www.example.com/app2) need to redirect to app2 without changing the root domain [www.example.com](http://www.example.com).

I expecting

1. app1 --> [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)
2. app2 --> [www.example.com/app2](http://www.example.com/app2)

Please guide me to acheive this.

Comment: with AzureFrontDoor we can do it [Refrence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm new to this concept. can you explain how to do this by using AzureFrontDoor.

Comment: will give you a sample example of how to use

Answer (score 0):

**Reference :**

> I built a prototype [web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/frontdoor/routing-methods) with privacy [settings](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iCN4JbZ9Svk) for the [home](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/quickstart-dotnetcore?pivots=development-environment-vs&tabs=net70), and I connected the web app service with Front Door.

[image]

- The relevant Front door that was built is accessible at the [Endpoint](https://i.imgur.com/d593SpE.png).
- It is necessary to establish the origin group and the origin.

[image]

- Add the [Routes](https://i.imgur.com/oSHodaK.png) to the new origin after upgrading the [origin](https://i.imgur.com/4i0JxBM.png).
- Click  ["add route"](https://i.imgur.com/H3DbxW3.png)  in Front Door Manager.

[image]

- After [route](https://i.imgur.com/2y7zDgS.png) creation When you click on [privacy](https://i.imgur.com/qspvP4f.png), you'll be taken to the default page.

**Output**  :

[image]